# How do I add behavior to a featherlight.js iframe "close" button

Tags: featherlight.js

I'm using featherlight.js and I want to add behavior to the "close" button when making a popup. When a user hits the "x" button I want it to redirect the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `afterClose` callback...

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it